# Match values and print sum based on repetitiveness in awk

Tags: text-processing, awk, csv

I have the following CSV files:

#### File 1

```
19997,20161108,FSM,EXCHANGE_2,GLOBE,0  
17541,20161108,TATA_MOBILE,WORLD,TELECOM,1  
34556,20161108,europe,state,0
```

#### File 2

```
EXCHANGE_2,CANADA,30298  
WORLD,INDIA,1123  
state,canada,2241
```

---

How do I create a new file that combines the two by matching column 4 of file 1 with column 1 of file 2? The result should be:

```
19997,20161108,FSM,EXCHANGE_2,GLOBE,0,CANADA,30298
17541,20161108,TATA_MOBILE,WORLD,TELECOM,1,INDIA,1123
34556,20161108,europe,state,0,canada,2241
```

Comment: Line3 of File1 has 5 fields, whereas Line1&Line2 both have 6. My solution below doesn't care, but you may want to fix that input data sample, or specify that you did this on purpose. @xhienne also noticed.

Answer (score 0):

Joining two files by a common field being a typical task for the `join` command, allow me to answer with something else than awk. This is `bash` code:

```
join -t, -1 4 -2 1 -o 1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,1.6,2.2,2.3 <(sort -t, -k4 file1.csv) <(sort -t, -k1 file2.csv)
```

Comment: Good answer. But it shows two commas after 0 at last line for me: **34556,20161108,europe,state,0  ,,canada,12**

Comment: @MohammadEtemaddar This is due to a missing field in line 3, which I assumed was a mistake

Answer (score 0):

How about

`awk -F, 'NR==FNR {l[$4]=$0 ; next} {print l[$1]","$2","$3}' file1 file2`

1st block `NR==FNR {l[$4]=$0 ; next}` is active while the first file is read, and puts the entire line into an associative array called `l`, using the 4th field as the key. `next` causes skipping of the following instructions for that line.

2nd Block `{print l[$1]","$2","$3}` is only active when the second file is read, and uses the key given in the 1st column of file2 to lookup the entire stored line from file1. That, along with 2 commas, and fields $2 and $3 from file 2 then gets printed.